# How to avoid {} when using aggregate initialization with empty base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, aggregate-initialization

C++17's aggregate initialization for base class is awesome, but it is verbose when the base is only there to provide some functions (so no data members).

Here is minimal example:

```
#include <cstddef>
struct base_pod
{
    // functions like friend compare operator
};
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct der_pod : public base_pod
{
    T k[N];
};

int main()
{
    der_pod<int, 2> dp {{}, {3, 3} };
}
```

As the example above shows, I have to provide empty `{}`, otherwise compile error will occur. [live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RWpBOYHiRmCEJHLp). If I omit it:

```
prog.cc:15:28: error: initializer for aggregate with no elements requires explicit braces
        der_pod<int, 2> dp{3, 3};
                           ^
prog.cc:15:31: warning: suggest braces around initialization of subobject [-Wmissing-braces]
        der_pod<int, 2> dp{3, 3};
                              ^
                              {}
1 warning and 1 error generated.
```

Any workaround or pre-C++17 way?

Comment: I would notice that there is nothing related with having base class in your example, you can remove it and see that the error is still there https://godbolt.org/z/0FpuQ5

Comment: @DmitryGordon I need this base class. the case I provided is just a minimal example

Comment: Pre C++17 you can't have base classes so it isn't a problem.  You would just put the class and all of its operators in a namespace.

Comment: What exactly are you using the base class for? The comparison functions have to overridden in the derived class for them to work.

Comment: Regarding the errors you show, it's the same with e.g. [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array): You need an outer pair of braces for the object itself, then an inner pair for the aggregate data. As in `der_pod<int, 2> dp{{3, 3}};`. But that won't work because the inheritance and the need to initialize the base class as well (leading to that initial empty `{}`).

Comment: @NathanOliver Sorry for the late reply. if the base is a templated class, CRTP will be useful here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still provide constructor, for example:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N> using always_t = T;

struct base_pod
{
    // functions like friend compare operator
};
template<typename T, typename Seq> struct der_pod_impl;

template<typename T, std::size_t ... Is>
struct der_pod_impl<T, std::index_sequence<Is...>> : base_pod
{
    der_pod_impl(always_t<T, Is>... args) : k{args...} {}

    T k[sizeof...(Is)];
};

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
using der_pod = der_pod_impl<T, std::make_index_sequence<N>>;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/89307665ff493c0f)

Comment: Why go through all the trouble of splitting `der_pod` into an alias template and `_impl` variant, specializing it, and writing a customized type identity type trait? Couldn't a deduction guide accomplish all of that while also enabling CTAD (so no need to explicitly write out the type and size)?

Comment: @303: variadic template constructor might indeed be an alternative, but there is caveat with that to avoid issues with copy constructor.

Comment: Ah, good point! But I do think the alternative version, with explicitly defaulted copy constructor, is not too bad: https://godbolt.org/z/o6j4sjPc6. Unless you find something inherently wrong with it, I think it should be added to your answer +1.