# Hide empty base class for aggregate initialization

Tags: c++, initialization, c++20, aggregate-initialization

Consider the following code:

```
struct A
{
    // No data members
    //...
};

template<typename T, size_t N>
struct B : A
{
    T data[N];
}
```

This is how you have to initialize B: `B<int, 3> b = { {}, {1, 2, 3} };`
I want to avoid the unnecessary empty {} for the base class.
There is a solution proposed by Jarod42 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55599689/7769147), however, it doesn't work with elements default initialization: `B<int, 3> b = {1, 2, 3};` is fine but `B<int, 3> b = {1};` is not: `b.data[1]` and `b.data[2]` aren't default initialized to 0, and a compiler error occurs.
Is there any way (or there will be with c++20) to "hide" base class from construction?

Comment: Why not to add a constructor `template<class... Ts> B(Ts... args) : data{args...} {}`?

Comment: Why is it a comment? It seems to be working, lol

Comment: This is such an obvious solution that I thought you have some reason not to use it. :)

Comment: It was too easy xD. If you write it as an answer, i'll accept it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest solution is to add a variadic constructor:

```
struct A { };

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct B : A {
    template<class... Ts, typename = std::enable_if_t<
        (std::is_convertible_v<Ts, T> && ...)>>
    B(Ts&&... args) : data{std::forward<Ts>(args)...} {}

    T data[N];
};

void foo() {
    B<int, 3> b1 = {1, 2, 3};
    B<int, 3> b2 = {1};
}
```

If you provide fewer elements in the `{...}` initializer list than `N`, the remaining elements in the array `data` will be value-initialized as by `T()`.

Comment: I've just found out why this is different from aggregate initialization. If you consider `B<Class, 5> b = {Class()};` `Class` will be constructed first and then moved, while by using aggregate initialization `Class` would be in place constructed, no move involved

Comment: @user7769147, good point. You can take `std::tuple` of arguments and use them to construct objects in-place. But the syntax will be rather cumbersome.

Comment: I've randomly found a solution that solves this problem, I'm gonna leave this as accepted answer to thank you for your availability :).

Answer (score 5):

Since C++20 you could use [designated initializers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Designated_initializers) in [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

```
B<int, 3> b = { .data {1} }; // initialize b.data with {1}, 
                             // b.data[0] is 1, b.data[1] and b.data[2] would be 0
```

Comment: That's still too verbose for me, that was a minimal example. My array member has a strange name that should be ignored by the user

Answer (score 4):

Still with constructor, you might do something like:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
struct B : A
{
public:
    constexpr B() : data{} {}

    template <typename ... Ts,
              std::enable_if_t<(sizeof...(Ts) != 0 && sizeof...(Ts) < N)
                               || !std::is_same_v<B, std::decay_t<T>>, int> = 0>
    constexpr B(T&& arg, Ts&&... args) : data{std::forward<T>(arg), std::forward<Ts>(args)...}
    {}

    T data[N];
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef96cfabdef85326)

SFINAE is done mainly to avoid to create pseudo copy constructor `B(B&)`.

You would need extra private tag to support `B<std::index_sequence<0, 1>, 42>` ;-)

Comment: Why do you need `((void)Is, T())...`? What if you simply omit it? Won't the remaining elements be value-initialized with `T()` by default?

Comment: @Evg: Indeed, simplified. Was afraid to only default initialize remaining elements instead of value initialize them...

Answer (score 2):

I've found another solution that (I don't know how) works perfectly and solves the problem we were discussing under Evg's answer

```
struct A {};

template<typename T, size_t N>
struct B_data
{
    T data[N];
};

template<typename T, size_t N>
struct B : B_data<T, N>, A
{
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Interesting solution. But now one has to use `this->data` or `using B_data::data;` to access `data` inside `B`.